# Breeze Web API Round Trip issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

Hi I'm trying to get Breeze to create a metadata store but its failing with the message
    `NamingConvention for this server property name does not roundtrip properly`

I had the same self referencing loop with the out of the box Web API and was able to solve but setting 
    `json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`

Any help or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Breeze `NamingConvention` facility supports **property** aliasing, not **entity type name** aliasing. Therefore the spelling of the entity type name must match the server-side type name exactly ... even if you choose the camelCasing NamingConvention or create your own custom `NamingConvention` plug in.

That's why I'm surprised that you had any difficulty with the table/entity class name casing.

I am unable to reproduce this error. Here is what I tried

- Added a 'foo' table to my database
- Created a corresponding `foo` class
- Exposed it from the Web API controller as a `foos` query action method
- Queried on the Breeze client for all `foos`

Breeze client had no trouble returning my (two) `foo` entities.

Note that I did not try to mess with the `NamingConvention` on the client. I kept the default ... which is that every client entity property name is the same as its corresponding server property name. As I said, the `NamingConvention` doesn't do anything with the entity type name and there is no representation in the metadata for a difference between server and client entity type names.

Do you think otherwise? Can you provide a sample?

**A strong word of caution**: **Do NOT change the Json.NET property naming convention**. All name aliasing must be done by Breeze on the client.

In general, one should not change a Json.NET configuration setting if the `[BreezeController]` attribute set that value. The only exception I can think of is null value handling; Breeze tells Json.NET to ignore nulls. I think that is a mistake ... and you can tell Json.NET to send null values if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I solved my own question. My table names all started with lower case, so when I got the round trip error it was because it would look at an entity such as refLookup which was being seen as RefLookup by Breeze but was also referenced an entity as refLookup (no camel case as thats the name of the entity). So I just named all my tables in the database with upper case characters. Hope that helps some one in the future.

Comment: This was the perfect solution for me. Also one more thing, breeze expects all of your column names to start with UpperCase.. I tried all of my columns changing to uppercase one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using two managers.  I found that if you are using the global

```
breeze.NamingConvention.{whateverYouUse}.setAsDefault();
```

it needs to be set prior to creating the manager.  Also if you are forcing the json serialization to a specific naming convention on the server the naming convention on the client should match.  I am using the breezecontext and as long as its set prior to the manager all works as planned..maybe you don't need the server side setting?